# Playing Video from Online URL works but from Local Path doesn't

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, video

I am having trouble playing a local video on my computer. I used a library called [Player](https://github.com/piemonte/Player) which is quite straight forward, and in the example project, it's using a Vine video with supplying a link at the top, and it's working:

`let videoUrl = NSURL(string: "https://v.cdn.vine.co/r/videos/AA3C120C521177175800441692160_38f2cbd1ffb.1.5.13763579289575020226.mp4")!`

Thus, in ViewDidLoad, `self.player.setUrl(videoUrl)` works.

---

I tried to download the Vine video to my local. I saved it as `aaa.mp4`.

- I dragged the mp4 file in xCode project.
- I added the file in `Copy Bundle Resources`
- Then I used;

  ```
  let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("aaa", ofType:"mp4")!
  let videoUrl = NSURL(string: path)!

  viewDidLoad() {
      // print(path)
      // print(videoUrl)

      self.player.setUrl(videoUrl)
    }
  ```

The video doesn't get played, but

**`print(path)`** - gives me: 
`/Users/sentiasa/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/67160785-1BDB-4046-BD58-A8C448938A4F/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/5456FF89-904F-4AE6-A90C-747B6A371745/Player.app/aaa.mp4`

and **`print(videoUrl)`** - gives me:
`/Users/sentiasa/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/67160785-1BDB-4046-BD58-A8C448938A4F/data/Containers/Bundle/Appl ... /aaa.mp4`

Please note that, if I give the path a filename that doesn't exists, it throws an error, thus I know the file is there (and exists) in my case.
What may be the problem? What am I missing? I don't receive any warnings or errors

Comment: Try using NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)! instead.

Comment: Bummm!!! Acee!!! Please add it as answer, so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)!
```

instead.

Comment: Can I ask something? If I want to use my local server's url such as `let videoUrl = NSURL(string: "http://myapi.dev/aaa.mp4)` and call `self.player.setUrl(videoUrl)`, it doesn't work; but it works on Chrome. Also, their vine link is working but same file in my api url doesn't work (again, both vine video and aaa.mp4 in my server url works on Chrome but mine doesn't work in app). Do you have any clue what may be the problem?